# How to draw 100 two dimensional shapes (like circle) at different coordinates in a single javafx template?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am working on a java fx template to draw 100 white dot-sized two-dimensional shapes to resemble like stars in order to create a night-sky-like look. I am a complete beginner to java.

I already know about how to create a single 2 dimensional shape but how should I create 100 similar shapes?

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Constellations extends Application{

 @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600,Color.DARKBLUE);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800, 800); // Set canvas Size in Pixels
            stage.setTitle("Constellations"); // Set window title
            root.getChildren().add(canvas);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

            Circle star=new Circle();
            star.setCenterX(100);
            star.setCenterY(100);
            star.setRadius(2);
            star.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            root.getChildren().addAll(star);
    stage.show();
        }

               public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);


        }
    }
```

I expect 100 dot-sized circles but the actual output I am getting until now is only one dot-sized circle.

Comment: That's because you're only creating one circle, and the "100" number refers to the X and Y coordinates of the circle, not the number of circles. For your task, you could make 100 circles by creating them in a loop, with random X and Y coordinates.

Comment: Working with graphics should definitely not be your first project in Java or JavaFX. You should spend some time learning the basics of Java and JavaFX first; many of the concepts and syntax of Java need to be learned before you can do anything meaningful.

Comment: You also seem to be mixing two concepts here. Why do you create a Canvas if you then don't draw on it? You are instead adding your Circle as a scene graph object on top of the Canvas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708509/randomly-displaying-circles-within-gridpane-cells-in-javafx/53709006#53709006