# Displaying an Array of Circles in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a checkerboard pattern using an array in `JavaFX`. I'm very new to this, so bear with me.

I currently have:

```
public class CircleArrayTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        Circle[] circArray = new Circle[10];

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            circArray[i].setRadius(20);
            circArray[i].setCenterX(20*i);
            circArray[i].setCenterY(30);
            circArray[i].setFill(Color.BLACK);

        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(circArray[]);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm trying to go about doing this completely wrong, but I can't find any resources to help. The end goal is to have an `8` x `8` grid similar to a checkerboard, and if I can figure out **how to get the children I should be fine.**

Comment: `addAll(circArray[])` isn't proper syntax. It should be `addAll(circArray)`. If you have any errors, please always include them in your post when asking a question here.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708509/randomly-displaying-circles-within-gridpane-cells-in-javafx/53709006#53709006) helps any.

Comment: Your code will result in a `NullPointerExeption`, you never write any element to the array and hence dereference `null` the first time `circArray[i].setRadius(20);` is executed. Also since you're adding the circles to the child list directly and never read an element of the array anywhere but inside a single loop iteration, why not add the `Circle`s directly without storing them in an array. A nested loop seems suitable to vary both coordinates of the circles. (Either that or you use some modulo/division-magic...)

Answer (score 3):

There is a few errors you need to fix the first off is as Vince said remove the brackets from the `addAll(circArray[])` so it looks like this `addAll(circArray)`

Next is to make sure every circle has been created yes you made an array but its just an empty array so you need to add `circArray[i] = new Circle();` to make sure there is a circle for every index

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        Circle[] circArray = new Circle[10];

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            circArray[i] = new Circle();//Adding this line to prevent NPE on circArray[i]
            circArray[i].setRadius(20);
            circArray[i].setCenterX(20*i);
            circArray[i].setCenterY(30);
            circArray[i].setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(circArray);//removed brackets from addAll(circArray[]) 

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```