# How can I make a button generator in JavaFx?

Tags: java, loops, button, javafx, dynamically-generated

I am trying to make a memory game in JavaFX and I want it to be dynamic (depends on how many cards the user wants) if the userInput is 4 then it needs to be a 4x4 matrix containing 16 buttons. The pictures should show up in a button after it is pressed using Action handlers. But I'm stuck on how can I generate the number of buttons depending on the user input.
As you can see in the code I have hardcoded 4 buttons. How can I change this and make the number of buttons generate depend on the userInput?

```
public class Memory extends Application {
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    GridPane btnGp = new GridPane();
    Button btn1 = new Button("Button1");
    Button btn2 = new Button("Button2");
    Button btn3 = new Button("Button3");
    Button btn4 = new Button("Button4");
    String[] images = { "file:clubs.png", "file:diamonds.png", "file:hearts.png", "file:spades.png", "img1", "img2",
            "img3", "img4" };
    String[][] imageWithLoc = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int userInput = 4;
        imageWithLoc = new String[userInput][userInput];
        int targetNum = ((userInput * userInput) / 2);
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        while (count < targetNum) {
            int numC = (int) (Math.random() * userInput);
            int numR = (int) (Math.random() * userInput);
            if (imageWithLoc[numC][numR] == null) {
                if (!list.contains(images[count])) {
                    imageWithLoc[numC][numR] = images[count];
                    list.add(images[count]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userInput; j++) {
                if (imageWithLoc[i][j] == null) {
                    imageWithLoc[i][j] = images[count2];
                    count2++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userInput; j++) {
                System.out.println(imageWithLoc[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }

        bp.setCenter(btnGp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: btw all I have done so far in the code is to randomize the pictures throughout the matrix every time depending on the userInput.

Comment: See if you can get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708509/randomly-displaying-circles-within-gridpane-cells-in-javafx/53709006#53709006